# How to check matching data and insert if it has new data in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am getting data from API and match with my existing records in  database and if I have any new value I want insert new value only. I am doing that with below example. Bit its insert all the values instead of inserting new value only.

Here is my code:

```
 $retailer_id = ZoovuRetailer::where('name', $name)->first();


        if ($retailer_id){


            $get_api = ZoovuRetailerUrl::where('zoovu_retailer_id', $retailer_id->id)->first()->uri;
            //dd($get_api);
            $history = $retailer_id->setFeedStart(FeedHistory::TASK_ZOOVU);
            $client = new Client([ 'exceptions' => false ]);
            $response = $client->request('GET', $get_api);

            if ($get_api){


                try {


                    $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
                    $brands = WcBrand::all()->pluck('brand_name')->toArray();


                    $existing_products = ProductZoovu::where('zoovu_retailer_id', $retailer_id->id)
                        ->pluck('offer_product_id')
                        ->toArray();

                    // Loop through the API data and insert new products
                    foreach ($data as $item) {
                        // Check if the brand is in the list of allowed brands
                        if (in_array($item['brand'], $brands)) {
                            // Check if the product ID already exists in the database
                            if (!in_array($item['id'], $existing_products)) {
                                DB::beginTransaction();
                                try {
                                    // Insert the new product
                                    ProductZoovu::create([
                                        'zoovu_retailer_id' => $retailer_id->id,
                                        'model' => $item['variants'][0]['sku'],
                                        'msrp' => round($item['variants'][0]['price'], 2),
                                        'offer_url_en' => $item['url'],
                                        'offer_product_id' => $item['id'],
                                    ]);
                                    DB::commit();
                                } catch (\Exception $exception){
                                    DB::rollback();
                                    dd($exception);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (\Exception $exception){
                    $errorHandlingService =  ErrorHandlingService::class;
                    $errorHandlingService->handleRecordFeedHistory($exception, $history);
                }
                $retailer_id->setFeedEnd($history);
            }

        }
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Looks like you want `firstOrCreate` https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models

Comment: or use the `updateOrCreate`.